# How to remove curved line in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, interface

I am undertaking a project which I am using HTML and I am using CSS for the first time. On one page I have a register form and on the other I have a login form. In both cases a line is appearing underneath the Header over both forms. Im not sure what I did that created it. I am including my code and a link to the webpage.

Thank you for any help.

screenshot

[image]

html code> http://snipt.org/Bjoi6

CSS>http://snipt.org/Bjoj2

Comment: next time please add a jsfiddle instead, much easier to get the whole picture that way instead of just two links to plain code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css, you both have `.content` and `#onecolumn` under the same css rules.

If you would like only the `.content`, to have `border-bottom: 1px;`

Add the folowing to your css

`#onecolumn { border-bottom: none !important }`This should fix it.

Comment: Didn't realise I had done that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
```

and

```
border-radius:20px;
```

from *#content #onecolumn*.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of "teach a man to fish...", if you open your html page in Chrome, then right-click on the part of the page that doesn't look right, then select "Inspect Element", the Chrome developer tools will open and help you see what CSS is being applied to render the page the way you are seeing it.  You can then turn CSS features on and off to help you pinpoint what CSS classes you want to remove or modify.

FireFox has similar tools, as does IE, but I'm most familiar with Chrome.

Comment: I am a frequent user of Inspect Element and a firm believer in trying to fix things or find a solution by myself. In this case I just couldn't seem to weed it out on my own.